# the dowtime block with a schedule

Tags: anylogic

I want to model the tour of the oss in the hospital rooms for the delivery of lunch/dinner or various assistance.
Well, I used a 'downtime' block controlled by a schedule. But at runtime this block does nothing[image]

U know why?
Tnk U
Miriana

Answer (score 0):

you define what downtime block to use in your resourcePool block... If you don't tell anylogic why to use the downtime block, then it won't use it.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this through the schedule.
as if "schedule + downtime" was an event and it would trigger the ResourceTaskStart! Isn't it?

Comment: OK, I don't understand! If in the downtime block there is "defined by" and u can choose between a trigger or a schedule, why this block don't start? I tried to put in the action of the schedule the code " if (value==true){downtime.taskStart(resourceTaskStart.onEnter(OssM6));} but give me a problem! Sorry, is a frist time with anylogic, maybe I have a gap!

Comment: "OssM6" is the resourcePool that I have specified in the ResourceTaskStart block

Comment: maybe your problem is that your downtime priority is 0, which means that if your resources are doing something when the downtime (lunch) occurs, then your dowtime will be ignored... increase the prirority to 100 or something